# Checkbox inserts only last value into database,php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, insertion-sort

Here is the php code.

```
 <form method="post" id="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

<table  border='4' id="atttable" style="height:100px;">
<tr>
<td align="center"><font color="black"><?php   $cur_date=date('Y-m-d');    echo $cur_date; ?></font></td>
<td colspan='20' align="center" bgcolor="black"><h1><font color="white">STUDENT ATTENDENCE</font></h1></td>
</tr>
<tr align='center' >
<th><font color="black">Serial No</font></th>
<th><font color="black">Student name</font></th>
<th><font color="black">Roll_No</font></th>
<th><font color="black">Attendence</font></th>                

</tr>

<tr align="center">
<?php
  $conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  $db=mysql_select_db('data',$conn);
  $qu="select * from details";
  $run=mysql_query($qu);

            $i=1;
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run))
            {
                $id=$row[0];
                $fname=$row[1];
                $lname=$row[2];
                $age=$row[3];
                $phone_no=$row[4];
                $address=$row[5];
                $roll_no=$row[6];                  
               ?>

            <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php echo $i;$i++; ?></font></td>
            <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php echo $fname,$lname; ?></font></td>
            <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php echo $roll_no; ?></font></td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="checkbox"  value="present" name="attend" ><font color="black">&nbsp;P</font>
                <input type="checkbox"  value="absent"  name="attend" ><font color="black">&nbsp;A</font>
            </td>

        </tr>

              <?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
        {
            $attend=$_POST['attend'];
             $SQL = "INSERT INTO attendence (fname, lname, roll_no,attendence) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$roll_no','".$attend."')";  
                           $result = mysql_query($SQL);

        }
?>


        <?php
            }
       ?>

       </table>
       <button type="submit" name="submit" id="sub1">SUBMIT</button>


    </form>
```

please help me to complete it,its been a pain.
whenever i submit,the last value selected for a student gets entered in the database.

For example:if i have inserted 5 students and checked their respective checkboxes as p,a,a,p,a.The value entered for all the students into database are a.

i edited above code completely to make it work but now its worse as it dosent show anyrecord on insert.

```
    <form method="post" id="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

    <table  border='4' id="atttable" style="height:100px;">
    <tr>
    <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php $cur_date=date('Y-m-d'); echo $cur_date; ?></font></td>
    <td colspan='20' align="center"
                    bgcolor="black"><h1><font color="white">STUDENT ATTENDENCE</font></h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr align='center' >
                <th><font color="black">Serial No</font></th>
                <th><font color="black">Student name</font></th>
                <th><font color="black">Roll_No</font></th>
                <th><font color="black">Attendence</font></th>
                <th><font color="black">Date</font></th>


    </tr>


    <?php
       $result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from details");
       $serialnumber=0;
       $counter=0;
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
            $serialnumber++;                   

            $id=$row[0];
            $fname=$row[1];
            $lname=$row[2];
            $age=$row[3];
            $phone_no=$row[4];
            $address=$row[5];
            $roll_no=$row[6];
            $date=date("Y-m-d ");  

    ?>

    <tr align="center">                             

    <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php echo $serialnumber; ?></font></td>

    <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php echo $row['fname'],' ',$row['lname']; ?></font>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['fname'],' ',$row['lname']; ?>" name="fname[]">
    </td>

    <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php echo $row['roll_no']; ?></font>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['roll_no'];?>" name="roll_no[]">
    </td>

    <td align="center">
    <input type="radio"  value="present" name="attendence[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" ><font color="black">&nbsp;P</font>
    <input type="radio"  value="absent"  name="attendence[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" ><font color="black">&nbsp;A</font>

    </td>
    <td><?php
           echo $date;
        ?>
     </td>

     </tr>        
     <?php
          $counter++;
         }
     ?>

     </table>
     <button type="submit" name="submit" id="sub1" value="submit">SUBMIT</button> 

      <?php             
   include("conn.php");   
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
      foreach($_POST['attendence'] as $id=>$attendence){      

          $fname=$_POST['fname'][$id];
           $roll_no=$_POST['roll_no'][$id];
          $date=date("Y-m-d");

    $query="INSERT INTO attendence(fname,roll_no,attendence,date)values('$fname','$roll_no','$attendence','$date')";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
            }} 
    ?>

    </form>
```

i somehow edited it again and thank god i got my desired output but got stuck again :| .When i insert data and go for updating it,only the last record is displayed all over the rows.
//this is the html code
    ">

```
   <table  border='4' id="atttable" style="height:100px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php $cur_date=date('Y-m-d'); echo $cur_date; ?></font></td>
            <td colspan='20' align="center"
                bgcolor="black"><h1><font color="white">STUDENT ATTENDENCE</font></h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align='center' >
            <th><font color="black">Serial No</font></th>
            <th><font color="black">Student name</font></th>
            <th><font color="black">Roll_No</font></th>
            <th><font color="black">Attendence</font></th>
            <th><font color="black">Date</font></th>


        </tr>


        <?php
               $result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from details");
            $serialnumber=0;
            $counter=0;
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $serialnumber++;


                $id=$row[0];
                $fname=$row[1];
                $lname=$row[2];
                $age=$row[3];
                $phone_no=$row[4];
                $address=$row[5];
                $roll_no=$row[6];
                $date=date("Y-m-d ");



                ?>

        <tr align="center">                             

            <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php echo $serialnumber; ?></font></td>

            <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php echo $row['fname'],' ',$row['lname']; ?></font>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['fname'],' ',$row['lname']; ?>" name='fname[]'>
            </td>

            <td align="center"><font color="black"><?php echo $row['roll_no']; ?></font>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['roll_no'];?>" name='roll_no[]'>
            </td>

            <td align="center">                    
               <input type="radio"  value="present"  name="attendence[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" 
                      <?php if(isset($_POST['attendence'][$counter]) && $_POST['attendence'][$counter]=="present") {
                    echo "checked=checked" ;
                } ?>                    

                      required>&nbsp;P
               <input type="radio"  value="absent"  name="attendence[<?php echo $counter; ?>]" 
                      <?php if(isset($_POST['attendence'][$counter]) && $_POST['attendence'][$counter]=="absent") {
                    echo "checked=checked";
                }?>                    

                      required>&nbsp;A


            </td>
            <td><?php
               echo $date;
                ?>
            </td>

       </tr>



        <?php
               $counter++; 
            }
       ?>

       </table>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="sub1" value="submit">SUBMIT</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="viewatt.php" id="butt">VIEW</a>

    </form>
```

//this is php code

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

           $date=date("Y-m-d ");   
           $records= mysqli_query($conn,"select * from attendence where att_day='$date'");
            $num=mysqli_num_rows($records);

            if($num){
                 foreach($_POST['attendence'] as $id=>$attendence)
            {      
                 $fname=$_POST['fname'][$id];
                $roll_no=$_POST['roll_no'][$id];

                $result= mysqli_query($conn,"update attendence set fname='$fname',roll_no='$roll_no',attendence='$attendence',att_day='$date' where att_day='$date'");

                        if($result){
        echo "<script>alert('Attendence updated successfully')</script>";
                                 }
            }}
                else{
            foreach($_POST['attendence'] as $id=>$attendence)
            {      
                 $fname=$_POST['fname'][$id];
                $roll_no=$_POST['roll_no'][$id];

       $query ="INSERT INTO attendence (fname,roll_no,attendence,att_day)  VALUES ( '$fname','$roll_no','$attendence','$date') ";
   $insert_Result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

                 if($insert_Result){
        echo "<script>alert('Attendence inserted successfully')</script>";
                                 }

            } }   
        }

       ?>
```

Comment: that's because you didn't treat the checkbox inputs as arrays.

Comment: can u show me by editing it plz

Comment: If you have multiple inputs with the same `name` attribute, and without treating them as "HTML arrays" (using `name="foo[]"`), only the last input would be sent.

Comment: consult the duplicates @SudhanshuSingh

Comment: i have done that earlier but it throws an error -->array to string conversion

Comment: i have just uploaded the new one plz help